# Internet Explorer WScript Shell Enabled

Tags: security, web, xss, csrf, exploit

While testing a company's systems security, I found out that they have allowed `WScript.Shell` to run in all of their Internet Explorer for Intranet websites. It works if you open HTML files in your IE or if you access any of 500+ intranet site. Their intranet websites and intranet domains are huge, they have more than 500+ intranet web sites/applications.

As an example, I told them if an attacked knew about an internal XSS (which they have tons), someone from outside can craft a URL http://yourknownintranet/vuln.aspx?xss=Wscript.Shell(....)
and send it to your employees with a good background story and most probably all of them will click.

They still consider it as low risk, they say it's Intranet only, you need another XSS for it, we need to have `WScript.Shell` enabled, etc.

Anyone can help me here to convince them that it's not OK? Is there a way to impersonate Intranet etc? What other attack vectors might exist here?

Comment: Maybe flag and ask for this to be migrated to http://security.stackexchange.com/. As long as you mean by `Anyone can help me here to convince them that it's not OK?` how you exploit it.

Comment: They are right - you would need some way of controlling what `Shell` calls. If it does this on arbitrary user input or there's XSS, then it would be vulnerable.

Comment: @SilverlightFox: You didn't get the question

Comment: I believe that I did.

Comment: It would be a great question for sec.se, however for it to be a risk you will need an actual vulnerability for the threat to exploit.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see how this can be intranet only. In addition to your phishing example, if an attacker knows about an XSS whole in their intranet, and external site can attack the intranet through a victim's browser. A victim is tricked into visiting external page A, which opens a hidden iframe which opens a URL which exploits a reflected (or stored) XSS in an intranet application. 
Some intranet apps are probably not HTTPS, and thus leaks their referer headers to the internet as well.

Maybe run a BeEF demo for them to show how an external party can control a user's browser through XSS, and execute stuff via wshell?

What if a device has malware and is brought into the company? What if a server in the company is hacked? This vulnerability may make it easier to move laterally.

Comment: That's exactly what I said and wrote in question. I even created a demo XSS -> RCE using an internal app. But they say, that attacker should know 1) They have enabled ActiveX on intranet 2) Hostname + vulnerability of an intranet application. They say it's EXTREMELY unlikely. So I need to do something more. It's on Intranet only for ActiveX. Is there a way to bypass that? I tried to iframe internal web app so it will be mixed zone, still didn't work.